# Country to live in for ~2 months when pregnant

Tags: long-term, pregnancy

What would be a good country to live in for around 2 months, for a family of 3 (myself, my wife and our 2 yo child), assuming my wife would be pregnant at a time with our second child?

Here are requirements I can think of:

1. Very good healthcare (in case something goes wrong with my wife or the fetus)
2. Preferably an Asian country (as we both like traveling there a lot), but other places are on the table too.
3. No dangerous, endemic diseases that could threaten the fetus or our young child.
4. Interesting (it's a trip afterall).
5. Availability of good internet connectivity (so I can work).
6. Bonus points for low costs of living
7. Bonus points for countries issuing tourist visa's valid for 2+ months at a time.

A bit of background: I'm working remotely, but my wife owns a business and being pregnant is one of the few cases she could possibly consider traveling for more than 2-3 weeks. We're probably going to do this (assuming I can convince her, that is ;)), but we need to find a place we're both will feel comfortable about (in terms of pregnancy).

During that period of 2 months, we might travel around for a month or so, and stay in one place for another month, where I would work and we would go out in the evenings.

Comment: This is not really the type of question that works well here. But, having said that: Northern Thailand.

Comment: Make sure that your insurance covers the very good health care (which is likely to be very expensive, even in cheap countries). One pitfall is that in case of premature birth, in some policies the child isn't covered.

Comment: @ugoren insurance is always advisable but good healthcare is not always "very expensive" once you get outside the US. It does of course depend on what you consider "very good" but quality routine healthcare costs peanuts in many countries.

Answer (score 0):

Thailand covers everything except #3.  But number 3 can be avoided with a little care and precaution.

Comment: What kinds of diseases you have in mind?

Comment: It's a developing tropical country, and as such does come with higher risks of disease. From dengue to hepatitis to pneumonia to diarrhoeal diseases. Funny infections that the doctor puts down to it being warm and damp. But it also has very good healthcare for a developing country, and as Irked says if you are careful you can manage the risks. Child mortality is over 3x the EU for example. But that's good for a developing country. I've had quite a lot of experience with the hospitals and it has all been good. For "Asia", "cheap" and "good healthcare" I don't think you'll find better.